# How to Round Adjust in VB.NEt

Tags: vb.net

How to round adjust a value? eg: 200.58 = 200.60

i have tried

> roundup(double) as int      roundup = rounddown(double + 0.5)
>     end_roundup

I'm new to VB.net. Please help me out with this problem.

Help needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As was stated in the comments you can use the [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myValue As Double = 200.58

    myValue = Math.Round(myValue, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

    Console.WriteLine(myValue) 'Displays 200.6
    Console.WriteLine(myValue.ToString("0.00")) 'Displays 200.60 as your example showed
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim val As Double = 200.58

    MsgBox(Math.Round(val, 1).ToString("0.00"))
```